# PyQT5 Add 2nd Layout below Gridview widget

Tags: python, gridview, pyqt5

Good day! I hope someone can tell me where I am going wrong with the following simple code. I am displaying images in a gridview (shown as buttons for simplicity below) These use the usual row and columns to display in formation. My issue is under the gridview I wish to add two independent buttons (ok/cancel). These I don't want to be part of grid but on their own underneath.

From many hours of messing around I thought I would need to add my grid view to a vertical box i.e top slot and then the buttons i've made to the bottom one but i'm not sure of the correct way to achieve this. My poor attempt at this code is below. One thing to mention is the completed gridview is passed into a scrollable area. I don't know if that's why I don't see the buttons appear in my example. Thank you

Hoping for it to look like this [image]

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title = "Lost with widgets"
        self.main_window()

    def main_window(self):
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(0, 0, 600, 600)
        # Make Grid
        self.grid = QGridLayout()
        self.grid.setSpacing(100)
        # Make buttons
        folder_button = QPushButton('Top Buttons 1', self)
        self.grid.addWidget(folder_button, 0, 1, alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)  # Add to grid
        folder_button1 = QPushButton('Top Buttons 2', self)
        self.grid.addWidget(folder_button1, 0, 2, alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)  # Add to grid
        # Complete layout of Grid
        self.setLayout(self.grid)
        #########################################################
        # Create Ok and Cancel bottom buttons#
        ########################################################
        okButton = QPushButton("OK")
        cancelButton = QPushButton("Cancel")
        # Horizonal
        hbox = QHBoxLayout()
        hbox.addStretch(1)
        hbox.addWidget(okButton)
        hbox.addWidget(cancelButton)
        # Vertical
        vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        vbox.addStretch(1)
        vbox.addLayout(hbox)
        # Set layout
        self.setLayout(hbox)
        # add widget and set its layout
        wrapper_widget = QWidget()
        wrapper_widget.setLayout(self.grid)
        # Scroll
        scroll = QScrollArea()
        scroll.setWidget(wrapper_widget)
        scroll.setSizeAdjustPolicy(scroll.AdjustToContents)
        scroll.setWidgetResizable(False) # Spaces out
        self.setCentralWidget(scroll)
        # Show
        self.show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you set `scroll` widget as central widget. `scroll` widget contains only `wrapper_widget`, which contains `gridlayout`, not `vbox`.

Try creating `vbox` and add `scroll` widget and `hbox` to `vbox`, and set central widget with `QWidget` which has `vbox` layout.

I modified some of your code, adding `master_widget` which has `vbox` layout that contains `scroll` and `hbox` layout. Check this!

```
class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title = "Lost with widgets"
        self.main_window()

    def main_window(self):
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(0, 0, 600, 600)
        # Make Grid
        self.grid = QGridLayout()
        self.grid.setSpacing(100)
        # Make buttons
        folder_button = QPushButton('Top Buttons 1', self)
        self.grid.addWidget(folder_button, 0, 1, alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)  # Add to grid
        folder_button1 = QPushButton('Top Buttons 2', self)
        self.grid.addWidget(folder_button1, 0, 2, alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)  # Add to grid
        # Complete layout of Grid
        self.setLayout(self.grid)
        #########################################################
        # Create Ok and Cancel bottom buttons#
        ########################################################
        okButton = QPushButton("OK")
        cancelButton = QPushButton("Cancel")
        # Horizonal
        hbox = QHBoxLayout()
        hbox.addStretch(1)
        hbox.addWidget(okButton)
        hbox.addWidget(cancelButton)
        # Vertical
        vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        vbox.addStretch(1)
        # vbox.addLayout(hbox)
        # Set layout
        # self.setLayout(vbox)
        # add widget and set its layout
        wrapper_widget = QWidget()
        wrapper_widget.setLayout(self.grid)
        # Scroll
        scroll = QScrollArea()
        scroll.setWidget(wrapper_widget)
        # scroll.setSizeAdjustPolicy(scroll.AdjustToContents)
        scroll.setWidgetResizable(False) # Spaces out
        master_widget = QWidget()
        master_widget.setLayout(vbox)
        vbox.addWidget(scroll)
        vbox.addLayout(hbox)
        self.setCentralWidget(master_widget)
        # Show
        self.show()
```